# overflow:hidden not hiding scrollbar in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to hide the appearance of the scrollbar but will still be able to scroll. So far, it works fine on Chrome however when it's in Firefox it does not work. So i tried the solution given which is to put it inside a wrapper and use overflow:hidden but still it shows the scroll in firefox.

Does anyone know any alternative way to hide the css of the scrollbar in firefox? *also note im using bootstrap

```
<div class="menu-desktop-nav col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 position-relative" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <ul class="nav menu-nav-li rounded-menu position-relative" id="menu-nav">
            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 top-active" data-id="anchor_1">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Traditional Pizza</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_2">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Burgers</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_3">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Steak</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_4">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Pasta</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_5">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Sides</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_6">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Dessert</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_7">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Drinks</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_8">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Alcohol</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_9">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Deals</a>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item menu-nav-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold pt-4 pb-4 " data-id="anchor_10">
                <a href="#" class=" nav-link">Coffee</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try style="overflow-hidden !important;"

Comment: @WiniSan The scrollbar still shows even when i use !important on the wrapper

Comment: Okay. Maybe, one of the bootstrap classes causing the issue. Is the position-relative class really required?

Comment: @WiniSan Yeah but even i take out the bootstrap classes on that div the scrollbar still shows up

Comment: Scrollbar appears only in this particular box or whole page? Did you tried to use `overflow: hidden` on body / html element?

Comment: @JohnEhrmantraut just tried it now, all scrollbars disappeared except for in that div. ;; I did try the code in jsfiddle and the scrollbar was hidden. but when it's in our site it does not show, maybe it is in conflict with bootstrap or some class ;;

Comment: Create JsFiddle please and send it over

Comment: I just pasted your code to JsFiddle and I cannot replicate that. It works fine on Firefox. I believe your CSS is doing something bad with that